# Is the reward following after time step $t+1$ collected based on current policy?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, actor-critic-methods

I am currently learning policy gradient methods from the [Deep RL boot camp by Pieter Abbeel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_gwYj1Q-44&t=1241s) in which he explains the actor-critic algorithm derivation.

At around minute 39, he explains that the sum of the rewards from time step $t$ onwards is actually an estimation of $Q^\pi(s,u)$. I understand the definition of $Q^\pi(s,u)$ but I'm not sure why this is the case here. Is the reward following after time step $t+1$ collected based on current policy?

[image]

Comment: yes, you are getting rewards following the policy $\pi$. After completing each trajectory, then you will update the policy $\pi$.

Comment: so at state $s_k^(i)$ the action taken is $u_k$ but for state $s_{k+1}$ onwards, the policy $\pi$ is being followed ? but the notation does not contain anything about $\pi$ in the $R(s_k,u_k)$ term

Comment: The notation $R(s_{k},u_{k})$ is not clear, but the rewards you get is following your current policy

Comment: but why would that be an estimation of Q ? if following the current policy it should be $V^\pi$ ?

Comment: You are sampling action($u_{k}$) from the current policy, $u_{k} \sim \pi$. So, it is like that, you are at the state $s_{k}$, from that state sample action $u_{k}$ from current policy $\pi$, thereafter following the policy $\pi$. By defination this is action value function ($Q^{\pi}(s_{k},u_{k})$). Don't be confused with:   $Q^{\pi}(s_{t},\pi(a_{t}|s_{t})$ and $Q^{\pi}(s,a)$ where $a \sim \pi$, those two have different meaning.

Comment: hmm how is sampling action from the current policy different from following the policy ? because the policy $\pi_{\theta}$ is a distribution of actions and $u_k$ is an action that is sampled from this policy distribution ?

Comment: Consider that you are following  a stochastic policy since this policy gradient algorithm gives the stochastic policy as output. So, $Q^{\pi}(s_{t},\pi(a_{t}|s_{t})) = \sum_{a} \pi(a|s) \sum_{s',r} p(s',r|s,a) (r+\gamma v^{\pi}(s') = V^{\pi}(s)$ and $Q^{\pi}(s_{t},a) = \sum_{s',r} p(s',r|s,a) (r+\gamma v^{\pi}(s'))$ where $a \sim \pi$